# Previously available promotions tab preview tool seems to be missing

Tags: gmail, gmail-promo-tab

There was previously a preview button where you could preview your customised promotions tab code visually before testing in an email but its to be no longer available at: https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview
This was useful please can you add it back?
Preview tool was also mentioned at https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/troubleshooting but links back to the overview page where it is no longer available.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your concern? you may add screenshots so we can understand better.

Comment: Doesn't seem to allow me to add a screenshot, thankfully I have one from before the page was updated. Let me know how I can supply or can you check the page before revision? The heading was preview your annotations and let you add your edited code and had a preview button below. As mentioned it was on the overview page.

Comment: Actually @twilight here you go https://web.archive.org/web/20230103090913/https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview
Basically previously there was a visual preview where you could test your custom code before moving to email test and now its gone with the page updates.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately this question isn't for stackoverflow, I suggest you post your issue/concern here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues or contact google support.

Comment: This concern has been logged as a bug under the issue tracker as suggested in comments. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/273883681 and will update with further information once I receive response.